# Django - Fastest way to query multiple primary keys in order to create a list of model attribute and uuid to return?

Tags: python, django

So I have a functionality that should return a list of a user's followers, with the uuid and follower username. The reason the User username isn't the PK is because I'm using amplify and it returns a UUID for user id. As you can see below I'm just querying for all followers of a user then doing a for loop to get each followers user name and creating a dict with uuid and username that goes into a list. I have concerns this will be pretty slow. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Model.py

```
class AbstractBaseModel(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<{self.__class__.__name__} {self.uuid}>'

class User(AbstractBaseModel):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class FollowUser(AbstractBaseModel):
    follower_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follower_following")
    followee_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="followee_followed_by")
```

View.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_followers(request, followee_id):
    try:
        followers = FollowUser.objects.filter(followee_id=followee_id).values_list('follower_id', flat=True)
        followers_list = list(followers)
        data = list()
        for follower_uuid in followers_list:
            try:
                username = User.objects.get(pk=follower_uuid).username
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(dict(error=f'follower id: {follower_uuid} does not exist in User model'), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            data.append(dict(username = username, id = follower_uuid))
        response_data = dict(followers=data)
        return JsonResponse(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except FollowUser.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(dict(error=f'followee id: {followee_id} does not exist in FollowUser model'), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you already have the UUID of the followers. In that case, rather than looping through them and doing a query for each, you can go faster by doing an [`in` query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) and getting them all back with one call to the DB.

So rather than

```
 for follower_uuid in followers_list:
        try:
            username = User.objects.get(pk=follower_uuid).username
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(dict(error=f'follower id: {follower_uuid} does not exist in User model'), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        data.append(dict(username = username, id = follower_uuid))
```

Perhaps you can do something like ( you might need to adjust this a bit to fit your specific situation):

```
followers = User.objects.filter(pk__in=followers_list).values('username', 'pk')
data.extend(followers)
```